# Not able to understand clockwise/anti-clockwise nature of the angles of triangle

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math, triangles, rotations

> If $A(z_1)$, $B(z_2)$, $C(z_3)$ are the vertices of an equilateral triangle ABC, find the value of $\arg\left(\frac{z_2+z_3-2z_1}{z_3-z_2}\right)$

The numerator can be written as $(z_2-z_1)+(z_3-z_1)$

Now, we can write both these terms in terms of the denominator i.e. $z_3-z_2$ using rotation theorem.

But I wonder whether to use $e^{i\frac\pi3}$ or $e^{-i\frac\pi3}$

Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: Don't make the unjustified assumption that the center of the triangle is $0$. In fact, if $z_1$ happens to be $0$, the problem is trivial.

Comment: @PaulSinclair hey, I don't think I have taken the centre to be origin.

Comment: Can you check the sign of $z_3$ in the numerator. I believe it should be $+$. In which case you should get $\pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @HariShankar yes, edited, thanks. Can you please tell how to consider the direction here? Clockwise, anti-clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

You should use both. What I mean is there are two cases.

- $z_1-z_2=(z_3-z_2)e^{i\frac\pi3}$, i.e., $z_1-z_2$ is $z_3-z_2$ rotated counterclockwise $\frac\pi3$.
  That means $z_1=\frac{1-i\sqrt3}2z_2+\frac{1-i\sqrt3}2z_3$. Replacing $z_1$, we get
  $$\frac{z_2+z_3-2z_1}{z_3-z_2}=\frac{i\sqrt3z_2-i\sqrt3z_3}{z_3-z_2}=-i\sqrt3$$
  The wanted value is $\frac{-\pi}2$.
- $z_1-z_2=(z_3-z_2)e^{-i\frac\pi3}$, i.e., $z_1-z_2$ is $z_3-z_2$ rotated clockwise $\frac\pi3$.
  That means $z_1=\frac{1+i\sqrt3}2z_2+\frac{1-i\sqrt3}2z_3$. Replacing $z_1$, we get
  $$\frac{z_2+z_3-2z_1}{z_3-z_2}=\frac{-i\sqrt3z_2+i\sqrt3z_3}{z_3-z_2}=i\sqrt3$$
  The wanted value is $\frac{\pi}2$.

---

More generally, if $A(z_1)$, $B(z_2)$, $C(z_3)$ are the vertices of an isosceles triangle $ABC$ with $AB=AC$, then $\arg\left(\frac{z_2+z_3-2z_1}{z_3-z_2}\right)=\pm\frac\pi2$.